# Navigate the single post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have created a new wordpress site. In the single post view I want a previous and a next button to navigate the other single post. here is the single.php page code I am using.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>

<div class="news_article_holder">
    <div class="news_art_cont">
        <ul id="anyslider">
            <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <div class="news_art_1"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/star.png" width="60px" class="news_star" alt="">
                    <h1>
                        <?php the_field('news_title'); ?>
                    </h1>
                    </a> <img src="<?php the_field('news_image_large'); ?>" alt="">
                    <section>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
            <h3>
                <?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found'); ?>
            </h3>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!--news_article_holder ends here-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What is the criteria of next? next in date? next in date inside category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links), its well documented.

There are a few options to create them, one of it is as easy as putting

```
<?php previous_post_link(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php next_post_link(); ?>
```

somewhere where you want it (documented [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link)).

Comment: here what i have tried <a href="<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>"><div class="prev_single">previous</div></a>
    <a href="<?php next_posts_link(); ?>"><div class="next_single">next</div></a>

Comment: Just go from the basic example `<?php previous_post(); ?>    <?php next_post(); ?>`  and work your way from there.